# Can't get a list of emails out from the members of a security group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So I am trying to query a group in AD, then use that list to create a list of email addresses.  I am using the below command:

```
Get-ADGroupMember mygroup -Server my.server.com | Select-Object SID | Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SID -Properties cn,mail -server my.server.com | Select-Object Samaccountname,mail | Format-Table Samaccountname,mail
```

when I run this I get the below error.

Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null or an element of the argument collection contains a null value.

At line:1 char:107

- ... User -Identity $_.SID -Properties cn,mail -server na.ko.com | Select-Object Sama ...

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Anyone feel like teaching a newb?

Comment: You should be able to skip both of your Select commands, and you need to wrap your Get-ADUser command in a `ForEach{Get-ADUser ....}`

Comment: Thank you @TheMadTechnician.  I knew it was something simple.  Silly ForEach-s.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician you should post this as the answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it an answer, you can skip the Select statements and run the Get-ADUSer through a ForEach loop:

```
Get-ADGroupMember mygroup -Server my.server.com | ForEach{ Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SID -Properties cn,mail -server my.server.com | Format-Table Samaccountname,mail
```